# how to join 3 table in mysql workbench

Tags: c#, mysql

Sectionname gradelevel and teachersid

How can use join table ? How can i link into the other table

Select a.sectionname AS sec b.gradelevel AS level c. Teachersid AS teacher

Comment: why have you tagged c#?

Comment: You do not have enough information posted here to perform this query. You must give us more information on the primary and foreign keys in each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways that you can do this. However, in order to do this, you must have a foreign key in the table to be joined. You may be looking for something like the following example, but I cannot give you an exact answer without knowing the fields of the tables.

```
SELECT A.SECTIONNAME, B.GRADELEVEL, C.TEACHERSAID
     FROM SECTIONNAME, GRADELEVEL, TEACHERSAID
     WHERE SECTIONNAME.ID = GRADELEVEL.ID
           AND SECTIONNAME.ID = B.GRADELEVEL.ID
           AND GRADELEVEL.ID = C.TEACHERSAID.ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*, TableC.*, TableD.*
FROM TableA
    JOIN TableB
        ON TableB.id = TableA.id
    JOIN TableC
        ON TableC.id = TableB.id
    JOIN TableD
        ON TableD.id = TableA.id
```